# Sliding Mode Control

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, power-electronics

I was going through some literature in power electronics relating to sliding mode control. I noticed that they have separately dealt with the reaching condition and then the existence condition for the sliding mode.

Question: Doesn't it imply that if the reaching condition is met, the existence condition is also automatically met?

If $s$ is the sliding surface, Reaching Condition: $s\dot{s} \leq 0$

Existence Condition: $\lim\limits_{s\to0} s\dot{s} \leq 0$